# How to store tree structure via JPA?

Tags: jpa, tree, unique-constraint, composite-primary-key

I would like to store a tree structure via JPA. The model consists of two entity classes: `Tree` and `Vertex`. Class `Vertex` basically contains just the vertex' name, class `Tree` a mapping named `parents` which stores the parent vertex for each child vertex (`child -> parent`).

This structure gives me simple and quick access to the information whether a given child vertex has a parent vertex and to the actual parent if any.

I use the following annotation in order to specify how JPA (EclipseLink in my case) should store the relationship:

```
@MapKeyClass(Vertex.class)
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "child_id", nullable = false)
@OneToMany(targetEntity = Vertex.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "bug_492_tree_parents", inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id") })
private final Map<Vertex, Vertex> parents = Maps.newHashMap();
```

Unfortunately, using the above mapping, I cannot store two child vertices with the same parent, like `V = {parent, child1, child2}` and `E = {{child1, parent}, {child2, parent}}` (thus, `child1 -> parent` and `child2 -> parent`) because I get an integrity constraint violation:

```
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '3-4' for key 'PRIMARY'
Error Code: 1062
Call: INSERT INTO bug_492_tree_parents (parent_id, tree_id, child_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

This is caused by how JPA / EclipseLink specifies the primary key in the join table:

[image: Incorrect primary key definition]

Unfortunately, EclipseLink choses composite key `(tree_id,parent_id)` as primary key. Using this primary key, it is not possible to store any tree that contains two different child vertices with the same parent vertex as in the above simple example.

Only after manually fixing the primary key (in the MySQL database schema) to `(tree_id,child_id)` I am able to store that tree:

[image: Fixed primary key]

I tried many different mappings; however, I always run into some (other) issues.

Finally, my question: How should or could I store that simple tree structure via JPA? Do I have to chose a different mapping? Do I have to change my model?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think JPA can do what you are trying to do.

When putting a Map in say an entity called E JPA expects you want to use a certain property of V as the K for the map and build a OneToMany relationship between E and V not between K and V.

Easiest solution would be to forget your Map and put a `List<Vertex>` in your class which only contains the top nodes also put a `List<Vertex>` in your Vertex class for the child parent relation between vertices.

If you want a structure more like you have now I think you will have to introduce an additional entity like:

```
@Entity
VertexRelation {
    private Vertex parent;
    private Vertex child;
    ...
}
```

Then your Map could become a `Map<Vertex, VertexRelation>` and you could use `@MapKey(name="parent")` to tell JPA you want to use parent as the key of the map.

Note: using the additional entity is just an idea and I have never tried it myself. I have always used something like my first suggestion for trees.